# Not able to run Gatling from Eclipse

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, performance-testing, gatling

I downloaded sample Gatling maven project from [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo) . I am able to run test from command-line but I also would like to run it from Eclipse.

I imported project to Eclipse as existing maven project and I installed Scala IDE. The documentation says: "Simply launch the Engine class in your IDE." And the question is how I can run that Engine class? Should I create new configuration to run it? Could anybody explain it please?